# Anyone know why I am getting CSC.EXE error on a SQL server install?

Tags: sql-server

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 on my laptop that has Windows 7.

I am trying to install Sql server 2008  and i get the following error

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

> Timed out waiting for a program to execute. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Users\cyabeko\AppData\Local\Temp\pc2gon7h.cmdline"..

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this?  I've been working on this for the past two days.  Thanks!

Comment: Off topic here. But do you really need the old sql2008?  Better make sure you verify and update your Fx 3.5 and Fx 2.x .

Comment: This might help: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/timeout-microsoftnetframeworkv2050727cscexe/cfcf144c-1d86-41e6-bdab-0b29dc140ed2?auth=1

Comment: The earliest supported SQL Server version is 2012. SQL Server 2016 Developer edition is free. Visual Studio 2015 Community is also free and equivalent to Visual Studio 2012 *Professional*. You should probably upgrade both your VS and SQL Server editions

Comment: SQL server 2012 had the same problem as 2008 too so I downgraded thinking it was a compatibility issue.  Thanks.

Comment: DenStudent, I'm going to try his idea when I'm home tonight. Yesterday, I cleaned out my temp files and from my control panel tried to uninstall SQL server 2008 and it was just taking sooo long so I cancelled.  Anyway, I'm going to try whatever ideas I can tonight.  I don't know why it's such a pain to install MS products.  Visual Studio 2015 didn't work for me either so I downgraded to 2012 and it worked.  I deleted my temp files both times.

Comment: Panagiotis, I had issues trying to install 2015 Community and that's why I downgraded to 2012.  Thanks.